# Создание Java - аплета (калькулятор) для запуска в браузере

Tags: java

Сразу прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос.

Есть **задание** - написать код аплета калькулятора и чтобы он запускался в браузере.
Я так понимаю, будет работа с графикой (визуальными компонентами), как создать файл в NetBeans и какой браузер подойдет для его открытия?

До этого с аплетами не работал вообще.

Comment: Что значит - чтобы запускался в браузере?

Comment: тема задания: ознакомление с запуском аплетов в браузере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда вам поможет [**данный видеокурс**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hn3Ni9fJU1M) по созданию апплета-калькулятора в NetBeans.

Вообще, помимо этого есть еще и другой урок. Оба урока спокойно находятся в первых выдаваемых результатах, если просто вбить [правильный запрос](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=netbeans%20java%20applet%20calculator).

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет данный [netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets_ru.html)

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению, не могу перейти по вашей ссылке

Comment: поправил ссылку

Comment: спасибо, попробую